# Turn an Array of Numbers Into a String and Back Into an Array of Numbers Within A Single Function With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

Essentially I'm trying to turn an array of numbers into a string, and then back into an array of numbers (exactly like the original array that was passed in) within a single function.

I know that this will turn an array of numbers into a string:

```
function arrayToStringAndBack (array) {
    return array.join(" ");
}

console.log(arrayToStringAndBack([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

> 1 2 3 4

But now, if I want to turn that string back into an array, this will return the array with quotes around each number (as an array of string-numbers):

```
function arrayToStringAndBack (array) {

    let string = array.join(" ");

    return string.split(" ");

}
console.log(arrayToStringAndBack([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

> [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]

What I *want* to do is turn this string `1 2 3 4` into an array of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

My idea was to iterate over each element in the string, turning the element into a number using `.parseInt()`, and then pushing that number into a new array:

```
function arrayToStringAndBack (array) {

    let string = array.join(" ");

    let newArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= string.length; i++) {
        let number = parseInt(string[i]);
        newArray.push(number);
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(arrayToStringAndBack([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

But as you can see this logs:

> [ 1, NaN, 2, NaN, 3, NaN, 4, NaN]

Why is every other element in `numbers` `NaN`? That does not make sense to me.

Comment: map to number: `string.split(" ").map(Number)`

Comment: Hint: what happens when you do `parseInt(" ")`?

Comment: I guess you don't have to worry about two-digit numbers?

Comment: @James I would like to account for two-digit numbers, yes. What about my code doesn't account for two-digit numbers, currently?

Comment: @HappyHands31 You're going through the string one character at a time is the problem.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery doing `parseInt(" ")` will give me `NaN` eight times - oh so it's counting the spaces as characters?

Comment: `array.join(" ")` make them become string with space in each other, and you use for loop to a string which include space. it will pass " " into parseInt and you got parseInt(" ") == NaN.

Comment: @王仁宏 Right so I can do an if-statement to check for spaces between the characters in the for-loop `if (character !== " " || "") {
            newArray.push(parseInt(character));
        }`.

Comment: `let number = parseInt(string[i]); if(!isNaN(number)) newArray.push(number)`
if you want to do that like this...there have a lot answer better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second attempt (with parseInt), there are two issues:

- You do one iteration too many: the `<=` in the loop condition should be `<`.
- You also iterate the spaces that are in the joined string.

You should really combine the idea with the `split` attempt. So looping over the *result* from applying `split(" ")`.

But it can be done shorter, by applying `Number` to each element with `map`:

```
return string.split(" ").map(Number)
```

The `Number` function does approximately the same as `parseInt`, except that it does not take more than one argument, which is important when you pass it as argument to `.map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use .map()

```
let array = [ '1','2','3','4']
let arrayOfNumbers = array.map( item => parseInt(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map both times!

```js
let array = [1,2,3,222222222];
let arrayOfStrings = array.map(String);
let arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(Number);

console.log(array, arrayOfStrings, arrayOfNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last part you're trying to convert every position of the string into integers, including spaces. So '1 2 3' turns into [1,NaN,2,NaN,3] because spaces can't be converted to integers.

This modified version of your code should work:
function arrayToStringAndBack (array) {

```
 let string = array.join(" ");
 let numbers = string.split(' ');
 let newArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let number = parseInt(numbers[i]);
        newArray.push(number);
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(arrayToStringAndBack([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```